# no enough space to install or delete

Tags: disk-usage, delete

When I'm installing or deleting packages an error message appears that there is no enough space...

I found a repository /source size 25.GB and the partition that ubuntu 15.04 works on is 31 GB

What should I do to delete the source? what other solutions you suggest to my problem.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for a repository to take that much space for two reasons: repositories are lists, and Ubuntu itself needs something like 13GB of disk space to operate. This leaves at least -7GB free, which obviously isn't possible. I recommend using mc0e's answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's not all that ready to understand what you are saying you found that's 25GB, but usually it's not packages that will be taking up your disk space.

You want a way to look over your directory structure to see where the storage space us being used.  You can't install packages for GUI representation, so that presumably means using command line stuff that will already be present.  Try this command which will list the biggest files and directories in order by size:

```
du -max / | grep -P '^\d{3}' | sort -th
```

The numbers are the size in megabytes.

Hopefully you'll spot some big stuff that you can do without.